# Regex for "{ [string] }" or "{{ [string] | [string] }}"

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a contract generator in french which search for things between "{ }" and replace them but I can't make one that will fit my needs.

Here's an example :

```
**Nom de l'{{apprenti | apprentie}}** : {train_PrenomPersonne} {train_NomPersonne}
```

The double brackets must be replaced by one of the two propositions in it, depending on gender. The single brackets must be replaced by values form the database.

So the final result should be :

```
**Nom de l'apprenti** : Chuck Norris
```

Will it be simpler to makes two differents regex for each case because they're not used the same way or a single one could fit ?

I just need a correct regex, the best result I could get by myself is a single match between the first and the last brackets.

Comment: So what are you asking for here?  Do you want a regex which can fish out the masculine/feminine versions of a word, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
{{1,2}
(?P<group1>[^{}|]+)\s*
(?:\|\s*(?P<group2>[^{}]+))?
}{1,2}
```

and take group `1` or `2`, respectively.

---

Broken down, this says:

```
{{1,2}                       # one or two {
(?P<group1>[^{}|]+)\s*       # capture anything not {}|
                             # into group 1
(?:\|\s*(?P<group2>[^{}]+))? # make the second group optional
}{1,2}                       # one or two }
```

You'll likely need to apply `trim()` to `group1` to get rid off the possible trailing whitespaces.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/iA8gJj/2/).

---

A possible example in `PHP` that replaces the found examples could be:

```
<?php

$data = "**Nom de l'{{apprenti | apprentie}}** : {train_PrenomPersonne} {train_NomPersonne}";

$regex = '~
                {{1,2}
                (?P<group1>[^{}|]+)\s*
                (?:\|\s*(?P<group2>[^{}]+))?
                }{1,2}
                ~x';

$replacements = ['apprenti' => 'Chuck Norris', 'train_PrenomPersonne' => 'Jack', 'train_NomPersonne' => 'Jones'];

$data = preg_replace_callback($regex,

    function($match) use ($replacements) {
        $group1 = trim($match["group1"]);
        $group2 = (isset($match["group2"]))?$match["group2"]:"";

        // now do sth. with group1 and group2
        return (isset($replacements[$group1]))?$replacements[$group1]:$group1;
    },
    $data);

echo $data;
?>
```

Which in this case yields

```
**Nom de l'Chuck Norris** : Jack Jones
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect ! It just doesn't take "{{ce dernier | cette dernière}}" because of the accent at the end.

Comment: @OnStandBy: The accent is not the problem, the whitespace was. Will update the answer but see https://regex101.com/r/iA8gJj/2

Comment: Ok I see, thanks a lot again ! I hope one day I'll be as competent as you so I could help someone else in my turn.

Comment: Now I'm stuck with preg_replace_callback(), I understand it with a single match, but in my case there's so much matches of diffrents kind I don't even know how to start.

Comment: @OnStandBy: I am not on my home Computer. I'll be there this evening and will provide an example.

Comment: Thanks ^^ I'll try to find this out while waiting

Comment: I'll use preg_match_all() and str_replace instead, it won't make my brain melt like that. But if you have time I would love to see how you would have done it.

Comment: @OnStandBy: There you go, have updated my answer using `preg_replace_callback()`.